# Return promise variable of main function after the "then" branch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the below code snippet. It has a function `fn1` that defines a `promise` variable. The `promise` stores the promise object return by `fn2`. I invoked `then` on that `promise` object and finally return the `promise`.

```
function fn1() {
    var promise = fn2(a, b);
    promise.then(function() {
        console.log('handling then');
        console.log('doing something');
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Since the `then` branch is async code, my understanding is when the inner function is async the outer function also behaves in async way. But the problem is the `promise` object is returned before the code inside `then` completes.

I tried to return the `promise` object within `then` as below. But this doesn't return the `promise` defined inside `fn1`.

```
function fn1() {
    var promise = fn2(a, b);
    promise.then(function() {
        console.log('handling then');
        console.log('doing something');
        return promise;
    });
}
```

Please help, how do I workaround this. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You may be taking the wrong approach (`return` after an async call isn't really helpful).

Comment: @Hodrobond - I need the promise object to be returned because another piece of code is using this promise object to do something else. What's the workaround to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this:

```
function fn1() {
  var promise = fn2(a, b);
  return promise
}

fn1().then(function () {
  console.log('handling then');
  console.log('doing something');
});
```

Or you could just do this:

```
fn2(a, b).then(() => { /* do something */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is the promise object is returned before the code inside then completes.

Then your concept of async is flawed. Async does *not* block execution. A promise is an object that represents a pending operation. It's what you hold to know if that operation completed or not. You attach callbacks to promises to know if it did.

What you appear to be doing is to know if `fn2` completed via `fn1`, doing processing along the way.

```
function fn1() {
    return fn2(a, b).then(function() {
      console.log('handling then');
      console.log('doing something');
    });
}

fn1.then(function(){
  // fn2 completed, fn1 completed handling
});
```